# Using numpy.where function with multiple conditions but getting valueError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a dataframe with multiple columns with numbers in them. It looks like this:

| H | C | T | P | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 200 | 500 | 0.3 |  |
| 500 | 400 | 300 | 0.2 |  |

I'm trying to perform operations on columns H, C, T, P and fill in column R.

For example,

```
df['R'] = numpy.where(df['H'] > df['T'] and df['P'] > 0,
                      df['C'] / df['T'] - 1, 0)
```

I would like the operation to be performed **row by row**

1. when the value of 'H' in nth row > the value of 'T' in nth row
2. when the value in 'P' in nth row is greater than 0

But if I run the code, I get "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

What do I need to fix? Perhaps I need to use row['column name']? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The error comes from using `and` to combine the conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use bitwise `&` and parantheses, rather than `and`.

```
df['R'] = numpy.where((df['H'] > df['T']) & (df['P'] > 0),
                      df['C'] / df['T'] - 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Though now I'm getting this error: "TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable." Any idea why?

Comment: The above line ran fine for me. That probably means a typo or that is coming from somewhere else

Comment: I see. So column T is actually a result of operation on column A and B (not mentioned in my original question). Could this be the cause of the issue?

Comment: The error you mention comes from adding parantheses after a series object like `df['T']()`. Check for something like that

Comment: It turns out that I forgot to put a comma somewhere. Silly me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'H': [300, 500], 'C': [200, 400], 'T': [500, 300], 'P': [0.3, 0.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

Create a function:

```
def calc(row):
    if row[0] > row[2]:
        if row[3] > 0:
            return row[1]/row[2] - 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Then apply the function, by row

```
df['R'] = df.apply(calc, axis=1)
df
```

Comment: If the columns change order, this will break. Also this does not use vectorization, which will make it slow on large datasets.